# Looking for drill bit tapered to match pencil sharpener

Tags: repair, screws, drill

I saw this once years ago, but can't find it now. It's a drill bit that drills a conical hole whose taper matches the cone left by a pencil sharpener.

The idea is that you can repair stripped screw holes by reaming them out with this drill bit, and then plugging them with a dowel sharpened with a pencil sharpener.

This seems like a really elegant way to repair a stripped screw hole.

Comment: What's the advantage over drilling a standard hole and using a standard dowel?

Comment: It just seemed a neater solution. Plus, I've repaired a number of doors where there was too little wood left over after drilling for a dowel. It seems to me that the least material you remove, the better.

Comment: I do not think it is "neater". The least material you remove means less material providing a secure connection, it would not be as strong as a hole filled with dowel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The product you saw was likely the [Veritas Plugger](http://www.veritastools.com/Products/Page.aspx?p=152), which is sadly out of production. The advantage of the taper was that it self-centered without making an oblong hole, and that you could readily enlarge a large variety of holes.  As you noted, the taper matched a pencil sharpener’s taper, so you could readily make the matching plug out of a dowel or even quickly whittle a piece of matching wood until it fit into the pencils sharpener. And, because it was a taper, a dab of glue and a gentle tap with a hammer and you had a perfect tight fit every time. The kit came with a flush cut saw (teeth set to only one side), but I just used a standard Japanese-style saw and cut it proud, then took the final bit off with a sharp chisel.
Sadly, I loaned mine to a friend and it was never returned.
I just stumbled on this thread when once again looking for a replacement, and I think I’ll try a standard taper reamer paired with an adjustable angle pencil sharpener like the Kusuwa Stad T’Gaal. The pilot hole is no problem, as the whole point is that you are starting with a stripped hole.

Comment: Freakin' A, that looks like it.

Answer (score 0):

You may have seen a taper reamer, there are a few different tapers. They are made to cut steel so wood is easy.

They would need a 1/16 to 1/8 pilot hole as they do not cut in the center. I have a few from when I worked in a bit factory. I expect they are very expensive to buy.

However, I would drill a regular hole and use a dowel.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon and other retailers carry drill bits with points shaped for drilling into acrylic and other plastics, minimizing the possibility of cracking and grabbing.

The angle may not be quite the same as a pencil point, however. The images I've found are varied, although my set of bits have a severe taper.